# Fetching data on textarea & dropdown doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to do an update page, the data that I'm fetching are input texts, dates, dropdowns and a textarea.

The data on input texts & date works completely fine however, the data on my dropdowns and textarea wont appear.

I still can update it, the only problem here is it just won't appear. So I'm hoping if anybody can help me and see what I missed in my coding.

**How my form looks like:**

[image]

**Solution:**

I've found the solution to this question and below is my new html coding. There a few php coding that I edited at the dropdown and the dates.

**Updated html code:**

**php code that are outside from my html:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require('db.php');
include("auth.php");
$noID=$_REQUEST['noID'];
$query = "SELECT * from daftartempah where noID='".$noID."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

**php code that are inside my html:**

```
<?php
$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
{
$noID=$_REQUEST['noID'];
$trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$pemohon =$_REQUEST['pemohon'];
$trkhMula = $_REQUEST['trkhMula'];
$trkhAkhir =$_REQUEST['trkhAkhir'];
$n_program = $_REQUEST['n_program'];
$lokasi =$_REQUEST['lokasi'];
$n_anjuran = $_REQUEST['n_anjuran'];
$catatan = $_REQUEST['catatan'];
$status_hr = $_REQUEST['status_hr'];
$submittedby = $_SESSION["username"];

$update="update daftartempah set trn_date='".$trn_date."', pemohon='".$pemohon."', trkhMula='".$trkhMula."', trkhAkhir='".$trkhAkhir."', n_program='".$n_program."', lokasi='".$lokasi."', n_anjuran='".$n_anjuran."', catatan='".$catatan."', status_hr='".$status_hr."', submittedby='".$submittedby."' where noID='".$noID."'";

mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());
$status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br>
<a href='Page8.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
}else {
?>
```

**Dropdowns:**

```
   <div class="form-group row text-left">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label"><b>Dept/Kelab/Anjuran: </b></label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <select class="form-control" name="n_anjuran" id="namaAnjuran">
        <option selected name="" value="<?php echo $row['n_anjuran'];?>"><?php echo $row['n_anjuran'];?></option>
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT kd_dept, desc_dept From koddept");
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option value='". $rows['kd_dept'] ."'>" .$rows['desc_dept'] ."</option>" ;
            }
            ?>                                      
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Textarea:**

```
<div class="form-group row text-left">
<label for="exampleTextarea" class="col-3 col-form-label"><b>Catatan: </b></label>
    <div class="col-8">
    <textarea class="form-control"  rows="3" name="catatan"  required><?php echo $row['catatan'];?></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My new form:**

[image]

All questions are welcome, feel free to comment and ask, I'll try to help.

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump $row['desc_dept'], what is the return value

Comment: **WARNING:** This has some severe SQL injection bugs because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use prepared statements. These are quite straightforward to do in mysqli and PDO where any user-supplied data is specified with a ? or :name indicator that’s later populated using bind_param or execute depending on which one you’re using. NEVER put $_POST, $_GET or any user data directly in your query

Comment: Why 2 IDs are sleeping in `<textarea>`? `exampleTextarea` & `catatan`?

Comment: Thank you for noticing! Now my textarea finally fetches the data.

Comment: Please show us your `php code` where you are getting the data from the `form`

Comment: @MarioA.Rawady I've edited this post. Sorry for the lack of information.